# strlen performance implementation

Tags: c, string, performance, strlen

This is a multipurpose question:

- How does this compare to the [glibc strlen](http://www.stdlib.net/%7Ecolmmacc/strlen.c.html) implementation?
- Is there a better way to to this in general and for autovectorization.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Todo: Document */
#define WORD_ONES_LOW   ((size_t)-1 / UCHAR_MAX)
#define WORD_ONES_HIGH  (((size_t)-1 / UCHAR_MAX) << (CHAR_BIT - 1))

/*@doc
 * @desc: see if an arch word has a zero
 * #param: w - string aligned to word size
 */
static inline bool word_has_zero(const size_t *w)
{
    return ((*w - WORD_ONES_LOW) & ~*w & WORD_ONES_HIGH);
}

/*@doc
 * @desc: see POSIX strlen()
 * @param: s - string
 */
size_t strlen(const char *s)
{
    const char *z = s;

    /* Align to word size */
    for (; ((uintptr_t)s & (sizeof(size_t) - 1)) && *s != '\0'; s++);

    if (*s != '\0') {
        const size_t *w;

        for (w = (const size_t *)s; !word_has_zero(w); w++);
        for (s = (const char *)w; *s != '\0'; s++);
    }

    return (s - z);
}
```

Comment: Related [Why does glibc's strlen need to be so complicated to run quickly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/57650895) has an answer that addresses the type-punning UB, and links to glibc's hand-written asm that's actually used on most platforms.  **Yes, x86 SIMD can do *much* better than this, doing 16 bytes more efficiently than this does 4 or 8, with no false positives.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this implementation is based on virtually the same trick ([Determine if a word has a zero byte](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord)) as the glibc implementation you linked. They do pretty much the same thing, except that in glibc version some loops are unrolled and bit masks are spelled out explicitly. The `ONES` and `HIGHS` from the code you posted is exactly `himagic = 0x80808080L` and `lomagic = 0x01010101L` form glibc version.

The only difference I see is that glibs version uses a slightly different criterion for detecting a zero byte

```
if ((longword - lomagic) & himagic)
```

without doing `... & ~longword` (compare to `HASZERO(x)` macro in your example, which does the same thing with `x`, but also includes `~(x)` member). Apparently glibc authors believed this shorter formula is more efficient. Yet it can result in false positives. So they check for false positives under that `if`.

It is indeed an interesting question, what is more efficient: a single-stage precise test (your code) or a two-stage test that begins with rough imprecise check followed, if necessary, by a precise second check (glibc code).

If you want to see how they compare in terms of actual performance - time them on your platform and your data. There's no other way.

Comment: Note that the comments in the glibc source file seem to be about the `#if 0`'d out code that's both slower and slightly less precise (only one false positive situation) than the above code. The code that's actually used (in the `#else` case) in the glibc source has false positives for **any** high byte except 128. Thus, my naive conclusion would be that the glibc code performs better for ASCII text but much, much worse for anything with high bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Also, please note this implementation can read past the end of a char array here:

```
for (w = (const void *)s; !HASZERO(*w); w++);
```

and therefore relies on undefined behaviour.

Comment: how so? we align to word size with the initial for loop and then iterate per word for '\0' a char array must be null terminated or bad things will happen. I'll update it with a less obtuse code

Comment: Example: an empty null terminated string is a char array of size 1. `*w` will read 4 or 8 bytes from memory, thereby accessing bytes past the end of the array. On most platforms this will work fine, but it is still undefined behavior.

Comment: Re: undefined behavior: Another user has just posted a question about that; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20312340/978917 . The consensus seems to be that this *is* undefined behavior, but that it's O.K. for the `strlen` that ships with a compiler to rely on only-compiler-guaranteed behavior.

Comment: Another [Q&A about reading past the end of an object in C vs. assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64).  It's definitely UB in C, but if you align your pointer, you can in practice do it without faulting on implementations that check accesses with page granularity.  (As long as the compiler doesn't reach any unfortunate conclusions while optimizing based on the assumption that the program contains no UB...)  `strlen` implementations hand-written in asm definitely do this, but C isn't asm.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, I think the naive byte-based `strlen` implementation will result in better auto-vectorization by the compiler, if it's smart and support for vector instruction set extensions (e.g. SSE) has been enabled (e.g. with `-msse` or an appropriate `-march`). Unfortunately, it won't result in any vectorization with baseline cpus which lack these features, even though the compiler *could* generate 32- or 64-bit pseudo-vectorized code like the C code cited in the question, if it were smart enough...

Comment: Compilers still don't auto-vectorize loops where the iteration-count is unknown before loop-entry.  So search-loops in general don't get auto-vectorized, unfortunately.

Comment: That's really unfortunate.

Comment: IDK if they choose not to because of things like valgrind that would complain about reading past the end of arrays.  That can't be the only reason, though, because you still don't get autovectorization when searching in a static array (or a function arg passed as `int arr[static 1024]`).  Just checked a really simple search of an `int` array with gcc and clang: https://godbolt.org/g/7xugwg

Comment: Oh wow, ICC does auto-vectorize it.  https://godbolt.org/g/6boZSh.  But MSVC, gcc, and clang all fail in this trivial case.  For a non-static array, ICC gets to an alignment boundary [so reading past the end of an object can't fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64).  
 valgrind would still be unhappy, though.